# How do I keep certain variables hidden from the user in pynsist application?

Tags: python, boto3, pynsist

I am currently using `pynsist` to package up a python application so that it can be installed on any Windows machine.

Is there any way I can keep certain variables or values **hidden** from the user? Currently the user can inspect and edit each python file in the application. This is fine for 99% of my application, but if for example I wanted the user to have access to files in a private S3 bucket of mine, would there be a way to connect using `boto3`, without exposing the `access key` and `secret access key` to the user?

Comment: You can save them to your own server and make the server do the job for you.

Comment: If you store your credentials with the application on the user side (running on general hardware) there is no way to prevent the user from obtaining them. You either need a specialized hardware or an external permission-based service/intermediary gateway (i.e. DRM) to achieve what you're after. Why would you even want that? I'd suggest reconsidering your requirements as more likely than not what you want to do can be achieved in a different, more elegant way.

Comment: Could you make the bucket publicly readable so your application doesn't need secret keys? If the user has access to those files anyway, they're not really private.